# How to add bash array variable to mongo update query

Tags: mongodb, bash

I am writing a bash script which updates a mongo document. If it's a new document then it creates a new document in mongo else updates it.
I want to pass bash array variable to the mongo query since few fields are of array type. I am not sure how to pass the array field. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my query:
`db.my_col.update({emp_id: '"'$emp_id'"'}, {$set: {contacts: '"'${contacts}'"', emp_name: '"'$emp_name'"'}}, {upsert: true})`

If I just add like normal variable the only first value in variable gets added.

Comment: why do you need a bash variable? can't you use js variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your array variable into a string, only the first item will be there, right

Basically, you get all of them with this syntax `${contacts[@]}`, but they will be unquoted and separated with spaces and likely won't work in a query because of wrong syntax.

So you'd need to manually convert a Bash array to a JS array. I don't know an automagical way to do it, but consider this function:

```sh
function jsarray {
    res=""
    
    for a in ${@}; do
        res="$res,\"$a\""
    done

    echo [ ${res:1} ]
}
```

It goes through it's arguments, wraps each one in quotes and joins together with commas.

Use it like this (I assume `$contacts` is an array of string values):

```sh
IFS=""
contacts=("skype name" "email address" phone website whatever)
jscontacts=$(jsarray $contacts[@])
# Proceed to using $jscontacts in your query.
```

After that `$jscontacts` will be a string value of `[ "skype name","email address","phone","website","whatever" ]`.

**Notes:**

`IFS=""` - `IFS` stands for `internal field separator`, this is how Bash separates arguments from each other. By default it's `" "` (a space). Resetting it to nothing to preserve array items with spaces in them; otherwise "skype name" beсome two separate values of "skype" & "name".

`${res:1}` - skips the first character from `$res` (because it's a comma).

`jscontacts=$(...)` captures the terminal output into a `jscontacts` variable.